# React-stripe-checkout Getting the shipping address

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments, next.js

I want to put a property in the schema to receive the delivery address they could help me with what I need to be editing I didn't find it in any documentation, but something like metadata: args but I didn't find a way to put it in the code please help me thanks,
in models / Order.js I would like to register the shipping address in the Order, in the pages / api / checkout.js file when registering the new order:

```
await new Order ({

             user: userId,

             email: paymentData.email,

             total: cartTotal,

             products: cart.products

         }). save ();
```

I would like to have an address field that will receive the delivery address of the checkout stripe form like this:

await new Order ({

```
         user: userId,

         email: paymentData.email,

         address: "shipping address"

         total: cartTotal,

         products: cart.products

     }). save ();
```

in the Order model:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

import Product from './Product';

 

const {ObjectId, String, Number} = mongoose.Schema.Types;

 

const OrderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    user: {

        type: ObjectId,

        ref: "User"

    },

    products: [

        {

            quantity: {

                type: Number,

                default: 1

            },

            product: {

                type: ObjectId,

                ref: Product

            }

        }

    ],

    email: {

        type: String,

        required: true

    },

    total: {

        type: Number,

        required: true

    },

    status: {

        type: String,

        required: true,

        default: 'pending',

        enum: ["pending", "delivered"]

    }

}, {

    timestamps: true

});

 

export default mongoose.models.Order || mongoose.model("Order", OrderSchema);
```

I want to put a property in the schema to receive the delivery address they could help me with what I need to be editing I didn't find it in any documentation, but something like metadata: args but I didn't find a way to put it in the code please help me thanks

```
import React from 'react';
import StripeCheckout from 'react-stripe-checkout';
import { Button, Segment, Divider } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import calculateCartTotal from '../../utils/calculateCartTotal';

const CartSummary = ({ products, handleCheckout, success }) => {
    const [cartAmout, setCartAmaount] = React.useState(0);
    const [stripeAmount, setStripeAmount] = React.useState(0);
    const [isCartEmpty, setCartEmpty] = React.useState(false);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        const {cartTotal, stripeTotal} = calculateCartTotal(products);
        setCartAmaount(cartTotal);
        setStripeAmount(stripeTotal);
        setCartEmpty(products.length === 0)
    }, [products]);

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Divider />
            <Segment clearing size="large">
                <strong>Sub total:</strong>R$ {cartAmout}
                <StripeCheckout
                    name="Conv. Calegari"
                    amount={stripeAmount}
                    image={products.length > 0 ? products[0].product.mediaUrl : ""}
                    currency="BRL"
                    shippingAddress={true}
                    billingAddress={true}
                    locale={'pt'}
                    zipCode={true}
                    stripeKey="pk_test_51H9DjUDvVpK1u7JvauE1t2VkVYyda6CGrlVy8az40uO9ELwXmQ3NFghlLIcTJDInZIazUlxLGMuUaMHhRjArCPB9008RvaFo7N"
                    token={handleCheckout}
                    triggerEvent="onClick"
                >
                    <Button 
                        icon="cart"
                        color="green"
                        floated="right"
                        content="Checkout"
                        disabled={isCartEmpty || success}
                    />
                </StripeCheckout>
            </Segment>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

export default CartSummary;
```

Here I am using the stripe checkout and I need to somehow get this token with the address and save it in order

Comment: What documentation are you referencing? If you need to request shipping address from the StripeCheckout component in react-stripe-checkout, you pass the `shippingAddress` props. However, your question wasn't clear to me, I can't see where you are using Stripe Checkout, where you're listening to the `token` callback, etc. Clarification would help

Comment: I would like to be saving the shippingAddress to the Order model